# FreeBSD: how can I check if `/dev/random` is blocking?

Tags: freebsd, devices, random

So this exact question has been asked many times about Linux's implementation of `/dev/random`, but I am struggling to find an answer that is FreeBSD specific.

From the FreeBSD [`random(4)` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&sektion=4):

> The generator will start in an unseeded state, and will block reads until it is seeded for the first time. This may cause trouble at system boot when keys and the like are generated from random so steps should be taken to ensure a seeding as soon as possible.

I ask this question because I would prefer that my scripts exit with an error instead of hanging because `/dev/random` has not been seeded yet.

Comment: Unlikely a script would be set to run so early in boot. urandom if you are depleting your entropy pool.

Comment: You could do it as with any blocking fd, by opening it in non-blocking mode, and selecting() on it with a timeout. Doing that from the shell is tricky -- a kludge like `var=$(your_blocking_read & sleep .3; kill $!)` may help. If your script doesn't really care about its random stuff being like _random_, it could just generate it itself, based on its PID and `date +%s` ;-) @user1133275 `/dev/urandom` is a symlink to `/dev/random` on FreeBSD.

Comment: @mosvy i'd rather they not have urand instead of faking a non-functional one. Is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html a alias to bash on FreeBSD?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/